# Is there a way to overlay an image permanently on top of the entire screen?

Tags: screen, 8.0-oreo, images, overlay

Suppose I have an image (say a `jpeg` or whatever format is nice) with exactly the same width and height (in terms of pixels) as the screen of my android phone (I have a Galaxy S7 edge running android 8.0.0).

Is there a method that allows to permanently overlay this image (with prescribed opacity) on top of my phone's screen, ideally without requiring root access? If the opacity part is difficult, one could build it directly into the image using a format that supports transparency, like `png`.

Comment: You can  try to draw a scene (which can include overlaying an image) using Tasker and see if that's what fits your requirement.

Comment: Edited your question to a) Avoid closure (asking for apps is off topic) b) delete portion regarding app development which belongs to [so]